# How to get variable labels to be saved as labels from R to Stata?

Tags: r

I have an R dataset which contains labels, that can be recovered from the command, for the dataset X as:

```
var.label(X)
```

after making use of `library(labelled)`.

Thereafter, I save it as a Stata dataset as:

```
write.dta(X, 'X.dta', val.labels=var_label(X))
```

I get an unused argument error message. I tried as well:

```
write.dta(X, 'X.dta', val.labels=c(var_label(X)))
```

to no avail. Any guidance on this is much appreciated.

Comment: See `help("write.dta")`; the function `foreign::write.dta()` does not have an argument `val.labels`, so that won't work. I don't know if there's some other R package that can save `dta` files with variable labels

Comment: Seems too straightforward to not have a solution. I am able to extract the variable labels using "var_label(X)". Shouldn't I be able to save this as a vector alongside ?

Comment: That may be so, but if so, I don't know of one. I know you can save datasets as dta format with `foreign::write.dta()`, `readstata13::save.dta13()`, and `haven::write_dta()`. However, none of those have arguments for variable labels. So, maybe there's another package out there that does it, but I don't know what it is. I offer my previous comment to at least give you some context of why you received the error you received even though I couldn't fully solve your issue.

Comment: Thank you @duckmayr. I am now posting a question that should be more general than this particular application,.